# Unable to apply styles to styled-component element in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to wrap a component with a `styled-component` div and apply some styles. However, for some reason, the styles aren't being applied, even though the ostensibly correct wrapper that is expected to be rendered is being rendred.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-engelbart-zh4wo?file=/src/App.js)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Very interesting. I used it almost the same way you describe in the project I'm working on recently, but there it's fine...

Comment: Also tried to reproduce the situation from my project in a sandbox, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to pass the className props, see here:

```
const Component = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>Hello World!</div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-lumiere-cq8gt?file=/src/App.js

I hope I helped you. Have a good day.

EDIT: [Check the docs here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)

Answer (score 0):

You need to container Component with `styled.{tag}` or `styled(Component)`
And then use that Container component to wrap main component.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default () => <Component />;

const Component = () => <StyledDiv>Hello World!</StyledDiv>;

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-hill-h8rbc?file=/src/App.js:128-189